Moviepy python - adding number counter to video for each mantra chant of 108 times
I am trying to create video using moviepy version 2 and python. the script takes input of image, chant audio and creates video. It is mostly mantra chants of 108 times. The below script I am able to create video for the static image but not able to overlay number counter. I want to display numbers for each chant till 108. how to achieve not able to get, pls help. I am using below script
    from moviepy import AudioFileClip, ImageClip, CompositeAudioClip, TextClip, CompositeVideoClip, DataVideoClip
    from moviepy import vfx, afx
    from pedalboard.io import AudioFile
    from pedalboard import Pedalboard, NoiseGate, Compressor, LowShelfFilter, Gain
    import noisereduce as nr
    from pydub import AudioSegment
    import os
    #import multiprocessing
    
    def process_audio(input_audio_path, output_audio_path):
        """
        Processes the input audio by scaling it 108 times, reducing noise, and applying effects.
        """
        print("Processing audio...")

    # Step 1: Load and scale the audio file by repeating it 108 times
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(input_audio_path)
    scaled_audio = audio * 108  # Repeat the audio 108 times
    temp_scaled_audio_path = "scaled_audio_temp.mp3"
    scaled_audio.export(temp_scaled_audio_path, format="mp3")  # Save temporarily

    # Step 2: Set up parameters for noise reduction and effects processing
    sr = 44100

    # Load the scaled audio for noise reduction and effects
    with AudioFile(temp_scaled_audio_path).resampled_to(sr) as f:
        audio_data = f.read(f.frames)

    # Step 3: Reduce noise
    reduced_noise = nr.reduce_noise(y=audio_data, sr=sr, stationary=True, prop_decrease=0.75)

    # Step 4: Set up the pedalboard effects
    board = Pedalboard([
        NoiseGate(threshold_db=-25, ratio=1.5, release_ms=200),
        Compressor(threshold_db=-12, ratio=3.0),
        LowShelfFilter(cutoff_frequency_hz=400, gain_db=6, q=1),
        Gain(gain_db=6)
    ])

    # Step 5: Apply effects to the reduced noise audio
    effected = board(reduced_noise, sr)

    # Step 6: Save the enhanced audio to a new file
    with AudioFile(output_audio_path, 'w', sr, effected.shape[0]) as f:
        f.write(effected)

    # Clean up temporary file
    os.remove(temp_scaled_audio_path)
    print(f"Enhanced audio file saved as {output_audio_path}")

def create_text_clip(i, duration, font, font_size, text_color):
    print(f"{i}")
    text_clip = TextClip(text=f"{i}.", font=font, font_size=font_size, color=text_color)
    text_clip = text_clip.with_position(("right", "bottom")).with_duration(duration)
    
    return text_clip

def create_video_with_audio(image_path, chant_audio_path, bgm_audio_path, output_path, resolution=(1920, 1080), fps=30):
    """
    Creates a video from a static image, main chant audio, and background music.
    """
    print("Creating video...")

    # Step 1: Load the main chant audio
    chant_audio = AudioFileClip(chant_audio_path)

    chant_audio =chant_audio.with_effects([afx.MultiplyVolume(2.2)])

    # Step 2: Load the background music audio
    bgm_audio = AudioFileClip(bgm_audio_path)

    bgm_audio =bgm_audio.with_effects([afx.MultiplyVolume(0.2)])

    # Step 3: Create an image clip from the static image
    image_clip = ImageClip(image_path)

    # Resize the image clip to the desired resolution
    image_clip = image_clip.with_effects([vfx.Resize(resolution)])

    # Step 4: Set the duration of the image clip to match the duration of the chant audio
    image_clip = image_clip.with_duration(chant_audio.duration)

    # Step 5: Combine both audio tracks
    final_audio = CompositeAudioClip([chant_audio.with_volume_scaled(2), bgm_audio.with_volume_scaled(0.3)])  # Adjust volumes as needed
    #final_audio = CompositeAudioClip([chant_audio, bgm_audio])  # Adjust volumes as needed

     # Step 6: Set the combined audio to the image clip
    video_clip = image_clip.with_audio(final_audio)

     # Step 7: Create text clips for numbering
    font = "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialbd.ttf"  # Change font if desired
    font_size = 48  # Adjust font size as needed
    text_color = "white"  # Change text color if desired

    # Loop through each repetition (assuming 108 repetitions)
    # Create a pool of processes for parallel text clip creation and composition
    #with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        #print("i am inside")
        #text_clips = pool.starmap(create_text_clip, [(i, chant_audio.duration, font, font_size, text_color) for i in range(1, 109)])
    text_clips = []
    for i in range(1, 109):
        text_clip = create_text_clip(i, chant_audio.duration, font, font_size, text_color)
        text_clips.append(text_clip)
    print(text_clips)

    #video_clip1 = text_clips.write_videofile("result1.mp4", fps=fps)

         # Combine the video clip with the text clip for this repetition
    print("video clip")
    video_clip = CompositeVideoClip([video_clip] +text_clips)
   

    # Step 7: Write the resulting video file
    video_clip.write_videofile(output_path, fps=fps, bitrate="5000k")
    print(f"Video file saved as {output_path}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Hardcoded paths
    image_path = "C:\\Users\\GuruprasadChandrashe\\Videos\\Youtube_Proj\\workingFolder\\image.png"  # Path to the static image
    input_audio_path = "C:\\Users\\GuruprasadChandrashe\\Videos\\Youtube_Proj\\workingFolder\\chant_audio.mp3"  # Path to the chant audio
    input_bgm_audio_path = "C:\\Users\\GuruprasadChandrashe\\Videos\\Youtube_Proj\\workingFolder\\tanpura_C.mp3"  # Path to the background music
    processed_audio_path = "C:\\Users\\GuruprasadChandrashe\\Videos\\Youtube_Proj\\workingFolder\\processed_chant_audio.mp3"  # Processed chant audio output
    output_video_path = "C:\\Users\\GuruprasadChandrashe\\Videos\\Youtube_Proj\\workingFolder\\final_video.mp4"  # Output video file

    # Step 1: Process the input chant audio
    #process_audio(input_audio_path, processed_audio_path)

    # Step 2: Create the video with the processed chant audio and background music
    create_video_with_audio(image_path, processed_audio_path, input_bgm_audio_path, output_video_path)

